# ¿como puedo añadir información a un selector con un snippet en javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, snippets

Estoy automatizando con un snippet en google chrome una tarea que hago repetidamente, en ella tengo varios selectores que me gustaría seleccionar una opción, siempre es la misma.

En este momento tengo que meterme en el selector poner el valor, pero no lo filtra ni añade .
`document.querySelector("#diarySchedules > div > div.search.ng-scope > div > div:nth-child(2) > input").value = "valor 1"`

Si alguien me puede ayudar, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Para buscar con `querySelector` se debe separar por espacios no por `>` asi :
`document.querySelector("#diarySchedules div div .search .ng-scope div div:nth-child(2) input").value`
una manera mas sencilla es poner un id al elemento y buscarlo por id.

Comment: Por ejemplo añadir document.getElementById(1)